# A Triangular (Non trivial) quasi-Hopf algebra

Tags: hopf-algebras

What would be a good (as "easy" as possible) example of a Triangular (Non trivial) quasi-Hopf algebra? By trivial I mean the quasi strcture not to be trivial, but if the triangular structure is trivial it's ok (it's actally better for me)

Answer (score 1):

Something like Drinfeld's twist of a group algebra will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the following papers:

S. Majid, *"Quantum Double for Quasi-Hopf Algebras"*,Letters in math. phys., **45**, Number 1 , pages 1-9 (1998).

C. A. S. Young, R. Zegers. *Triangular quasi-Hopf algebra structures on certain non-semisimple quantum groups*, Commun. Math. Phys. 298, 585-611 (2010).